# Where to find installed javadoc

Tags: java, dnf

On my Fedora machine, I did:

```
sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk-javadoc-zip.x86_64
```

Where can I find the javadoc I've just downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for any `rpm` package installed, you can run `rpm -ql` to ask what files are installed by that package. In your case:

```
rpm -ql java-latest-openjdk-javadoc-zip
```